# Where to see info about completeness of daily-build Ubuntu?

Tags: daily-build

Let's say I wanna use next version of Ubuntu which isn't finished, but daily build available. Where can I check completeness of system.

Comment: Why not use it and see for yourself.  I'm using Ubuntu 18.10 now, and the last  issue that I remember reporting was May-22nd (date from launchpad bug report), and it wasn't serious anyway.  Lubuntu 18.10 too runs well on my dell 610 (single core cpu, 32bit, 1gb ram; last issue 19-July on that was where I had to manually add a missing package - so not difficult; Xubuntu 18.10 runs too on that 32bit only laptop too!). What do you define as ready?  (this is opinion based, and off-topic here really - see https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @guiverc I don't ask how much ready it is, I ask how can I look at it.

Comment: At this stage of its pre-release development cycle Ubuntu is often buggy and unstable.

Comment: The best way to "check completeness of system" is to download and run a copy.  I `wget http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/daily-live/current/cosmic-desktop-i386.iso.zsync; zsync -u http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/daily-live/current/cosmic-desktop-i386.iso  cosmic-desktop-i386.iso.zsync` to download the daily zsync file; then zsync my 'daily-iso' & test using that (after writing to my boot-device). This means my bandwidth each day is far less than downloading the whole ISO each day (I think about 13% required re-download).

Comment: Development has really finished (they are in feature freeze), and have been some time now (since august 23), only bug-fixing is occurring now.  Refer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CosmicCuttlefish/ReleaseSchedule

Comment: @guiverc thanks a lot, I think that's the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to "check completeness of system" is to download and run a copy.

To grab the daily 18.10 Lubuntu x86 32bit) daily image, I [run each day]

```
wget http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/daily-live/current/cosmic-desktop-i386.iso.zsync
zsync -u http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/daily-live/current/cosmic-desktop-i386.iso cosmic-desktop-i386.iso.zsync
```

which downloads the daily zsync file; then zsync's the 'daily-iso' & test (*after writing to my boot-device*) each day. This means my bandwidth each day is far less than downloading the whole ISO each day (*I think about 13% required re-download last night*)

Development has really finished (they are in feature freeze), and has been since August 23rd; only bug-fixing is occurring now. Refer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CosmicCuttlefish/ReleaseSchedule

Comment: Just for completeness; this machine has 18.10 installed & I use it normally. When I upgraded my 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS, my test partition (same box, dual-boot) was 'bumped' to 18.10 via `do-release-upgrade -d`. I prefer this 18.10, so this is usually used (XFCE desktop is my favorite, box has GNOME & LXQt too for comparison with 32bit dailies).   I also grab the 18.10 Xubuntu (32bit) image and test that too (daily images only)

Comment: For the first Xubuntu x86 (32bit) ISO I downloaded the .zsync file, and had it zsync using the Lubuntu ISO. The saving was far less than usual daily images have, but was still significant and worth the wget & zsync commands.